# Apex Test Execution Page - No Namespace Dropdown Menu on Selecting Test

Tags: trailhead

I'm doing the hands-on activity for Security Specialist on TrailHead and getting issue when trying to run a test in Apex Test Execution; after clicking the "Select Test.." the "Namespace" dropdown menu is NOT SHOWING in Test Classes Dialog Box (See below Screenshot ).

I have already installed the required package(Trailhead Security superbadge managed package # 04t36000000jWht) before doing this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the browser's Developer Console (F12) to see if there's any errors?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Compile All Classes also did not work for me. Any other workarounds please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Navigate to Setup —> Apex Classes, then click on Compile All Classes

I have seen this happen in other locations like Schedule Apex, where some classes will not appear until Compile All Classes is done.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. it is now showing the dropdown.